# Ubuntu (budgie) 18.10 - nvidia geforce gtx 1060 nvidia settings fan control not working

Tags: 18.10, nvidia-geforce, budgie, nvidia-settings

I'v recently gotten a pc with nvidia geforce gtx 1060 gpu and intel gpu. I'm really struggeling with getting the fan control to work in nvidia-settings. I've tried to add nvidia-xconfig --cool-bits=4 to the xorg.conf file, but it does not work. All it does is leave my internal screen blank (tty ready), but my external monitor is working and displaying ubuntu.

I've read that the reason for the failing boot graphical display is because xorg.conf is obselete (?), now /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ is used instead? I've tried editing the 10-nvidia.conf file in there, adding cool-bits, but it also does not work (GPU overclocking is diplayed, but not fan control). If I don't have a xorg.conf file (/etc/X11/) then both of my screen works, but the fan is annoyingly loud.

How can I turn the fan off? The powermizer is constantly at level 4

Answer (score -1):

I have an NVIDIA 1060 6GB graphics card, and for the fan control I use "Green with Envy".  "Green with Envy" is a tool designed to enable you to manage your graphics card coolers, view information or overclock your NVIDIA graphics processor for Linux. There you can control the fan curve and clock speeds! Also I have the official NVIDIA driver installed, not the open source driver.